# получить первую пару ключ=значение в массиве php

Tags: php

Как в php получить первую пару ключ=значение в массиве? Например:

```
Array
(
    [6006] => 111
    [6007] => 222
    [6008] => 333
    [6009] => 444
)
```

Comment: Для ассоциативных массивов не существует понятия первого или последнего элемента. Для них вообще не гарантируется упорядоченность элементов. Все зависит от конкретной реализации - например, в сбалансированном дереве порядок элементов существует, а в хеш-таблице отсутствует. В целом невозможно предсказать в каком порядке будет происходить обход массива.

Comment: Можно и так: `echo $arr[0];`, где `$arr` это ваш массив сохранный в переменную.

Comment: @doox911, Интересно,а где это вы получаете пару `ключ=>значение`?  Вроде ничего не получаете, ибо ключа 0 не существует, а то и если существовал бы, то вы получили бы только значение.

Comment: @And замечания приняты. Ошибся

Answer (score 1):

вы не поверите:

```
echo key($arr);
echo current($arr);
```

можно, конечно, вариант

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v) break;
```

Comment: аххах, наверное это мой самый быстрый ответ на SO :D

Comment: а как же array_shift?

Comment: @EugeneNagornichyh а зачем? никто ведь не просил удалить первую пару из массива.

Comment: К тому же `array_shift` ничего не ведает о ключах.

Comment: @u_mulder это было как альтернатива `current()` предложено, надо полагать.

Comment: проблема с fancybox, такая же как тут ...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265675/how-to-reverse-the-order-of-the-image-gallery-in-fancybox

т.е. при группировке изображений всегда при клике открывается последняя картинка и можно листать только в обратном порядке
решил попробывать добавить стиль к первой паре из массива и застрял